# Find the first missing date in a column (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to find the first missing date in a date column from plan_table table. which should not be in holiday_table or it should be belongs to any week end.

holiday_table stores all the holiday dates.

Plan_table contains dates. here we have to find the first missing date

```
Plan_id      Date 
1           10/2/2016
2           10/3/2016
3           10/6/2016
4           10/9/2016
5           10/10/2016
6           10/12/2016
7           10/13/2016
8           10/16/2016
```

Here the first missing date is  10/4/2016, but if this date is in holiday_table then we have to show 10/5/2016 or next first occurrence..

Please help me to write a query for the same.

Comment: no sagi, plan_table contains these dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the LEAD analytic function like this

```
 select d
 from 
  (
    select
      date + 1  as d
    from 
    (
      select 
        date, 
        lead(date) over(order by date)  as next_date
        from 
        (
          select date   from plan_table
        union
          select date from holliday_table
         )
      order by date
    )
    where 
      trunc(date) + 1 < trunc(next_date)
    order by d 
  )
  where rownum = 1
 ;
```

Comment: Thanks scurik. I will be included with weekend. still I got what I need it.